# Polymorphic relation in a Trait in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My application has two types of businesses, from two different tables:

**fr_businesses** and **intl_businesses**.

I have a table **downloaded_reports** with a column **country** and a column **identifier**.

Since you can download a report for one of the two types of businesses, I wanted to have a morphTo() relationship in my DownloadedReport model.

However, the two business tables don't have the same identifier "name": in **fr_businesses**, the *identifier* is called "siren" and in **intl_businesses**, the *identifier* is called "identifier".

I need a way to tell Laravel that if the data in

> downloadedReport->country === "FR"

, go search in the **fr_businesses** table or else search in the **intl_businesses**.

Am I being clear? I really don't get how to do this and it's driving me insane! I'm using Laravel 5.8 if that makes a difference.

In my DownloadedReport model:

```
 public function business()
{
    return $this->morphTo(
        "business",
        "country",
        "identifier",
        $this->getCountry()=== "FR" ? "siren": "identifier"
    );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you solve your problem? How?